# Using Telerik rad captcha with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, telerik-radcaptcha

I am new to telerik controls. 
I have a aspx form with HTML controls on it. Data will be submitted using post method. I want to use Telerik Captcha on my page.

I have added following code on my aspx page :

```
<form id="frmYourDetails" runat="server" method="post" action="save.aspx">
Number: <input type="text" name="CustomerNumber" id="CustomerNumber" pattern="\d{2}-(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{1}" maxlength="19" title="xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-x" required >
Name :  <input type="text" name ="CustomerName" id ="CustomerName" required >

<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
<telerik:RadCaptcha ID="RadCaptcha1" Runat="server" ErrorMessage="The code you entered is not valid." Display="Dynamic"></telerik:RadCaptcha>

<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Save</button>
</form>
```

How do i validate if user has entered correct value in textbox that comes with RadCaptcha? I want this validation on client side if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captchas do not validate on the client, only on the sever for security reasons (if they did on the client they would be next to useless).

Call the `Validate()` method of the captcha or the page and check the `IsValid` property of the captcha.

You can see more options by using the RadCaptcha events in this demo http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/captcha/examples/serversideevents/defaultcs.aspx